# Android - Get data from many webservice (JSON) on a fragment same time

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-fragments

I am developing a fragment that allow get data from many webservice (JSON) same time. Let's imagine with this image:
[**demo image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEX3s.png)

- Request data ( this method will call a function that download json and send the response via callback listener

> ```
> > @Override
>     public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         BaseDataReponsitory baseDataReponsitory = new BaseDataReponsitory();
>         baseDataReponsitory.getDataFromURL(url1, this);
>         baseDataReponsitory.getDataFromURL(url2, this);
>     }
> ```

- Receive data:

> ```
>  @Override
>     public void loadListFromURLFinish(String json) {
>         ListEntity listEntity = gson.fromJson(json, ListEntity.class);
>         mList.addAll(listEntity.getEntityList());
>         Log.d(TAG, "loadListFromURLFinish: " + mList.size());
>     }
> ```

Data log is 4 and 9 . It is correct ( JSON 1 has 4 element, JSON 2 has 9 element). 
My question is how I split data to set for view (see the above image)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to add a secondary parameter to your callback to differentiate the call e.g.

```
public static final int CODE_1 = 1;
public static final int CODE_2 = 2;
@Override
    public void loadListFromURLFinish(String json, int requestCode) {
        if(requestCode == CODE_1) // do stuff
        else if(requestCode == CODE_2) // do other stuff
    }
```

And you would call it like this

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        BaseDataReponsitory baseDataReponsitory = new BaseDataReponsitory();
        baseDataReponsitory.getDataFromURL(url1, this, CODE_1);
        baseDataReponsitory.getDataFromURL(url2, this, CODE_2);
    }
```

And when you call the callback you pass the `CODE_X` variable with it so you can differentiate.

Comment: Thank for your solution, I will try it. I have another problem about this. Do I need use Async Task when receiving data? I found that data log is delay some seconds before I saw it.

Comment: @Brascelok You don't necessarily need `AsyncTask` but you have to do any network calls on a `non ui-thread` and `AsyncTask` does that for you.

Comment: I have already used AsyncTask on function baseDataReponsitory.getDataFromURL when download the json string.

Comment: What is solution if I send many request that is undefined, not predefined ( not is 2 or 3 url...)

Comment: @Brascelok Please open a new question for that.